# idiorm view sql for debug

Tags: php, mysql, idiorm

Using https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm for my php website.

How do I view the actual SQL that is generate?

ie:

```
$sql        = ORM::for_table('tbl')->create();
$sql->set(array(
    'another_id'=> $another_id,
    'name'  => $name,
    'active'    => 0
));
$sql->save();
```

Is generating an error, would like to view the output T-SQL, sometimes its just better to debug that way.

Ta

Comment: What error is being generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure using the set() is usually for updating records(that could be wrong). I would just do this:

```
$sql = ORM::for_table('tbl')->create();

$sql->another_id = $another_id;
$sql->name = $name;
$sql->active = 0;

$sql->save();
```

As far as getting the query, there is a 'logging' option in the config as well as a get_last_query function.

Comment: That is interesting, I've been using the set() all over the website, only ran into a problem now. The data type in sql is bit, I changed that to int, now it works, hmmmm.. will try your method, its the same as in the documentation, I didnt notice my difference until you pointed it out. tx!

Comment: I believe if you turn on logging in the config, there is a get_last_query function.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
print_r(ORM::getLastStatement(),true)
```